# how to rectify "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError" while using log4j in our class?

Tags: java, logging

I have downloaded "apache-log4j-2.0-beta9-bin" from  http://logging.apache.org/log4j/ and extaracted it and added to my project. Then I wrote a configuration properties file in my project as below

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
log = X:\logs
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/log.out

# Define the layout for file appender
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n
```

and I wrote sample program to test it, the sample program is shown below.

```
public class Log4jExample {

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Log4jExample.class.getName());


public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{

 log.debug("Hello this is an debug message");
 log.info("Hello this is an info message");
}


}
```

While executing it am receiving this error, please advice.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flume/Event
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at  org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginManager.decode(PluginManager.java:241)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:152)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:130)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(PatternParser.java:116)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(PatternParser.java:102)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createPatternParser(PatternLayout.java:183)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:115)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createLayout(PatternLayout.java:219)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:51)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(LoggerContext.java:63)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:217)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:114)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:81)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:83)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:34)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:200)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger$PrivateManager.getContext(Logger.java:61)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:39)
at log4j.Log4jExample.<clinit>(Log4jExample.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flume.Event
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 21 more
```

Exception in thread "main" Java Result: 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the jar: flume-ng-sdk-1.3.1.jar. You can download it from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/f/Downloadflumengsdk131jar.htm)

Comment: Its working fine, thanks. I need another favour, I can't find any log file in the specified directory. Is there any other way to locate it.

Comment: @mahes_SA_JEY about which log file are you talking about?? Which server are you using??

Comment: am directing  file appender to create a log file "${log}/log.out". I need to view that log file. I am using Tomcat 7.0.34..

Answer (score 0):

Seems you don't include Apache Flume in your project. Even manually from http://flume.apache.org/ or by Maven http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html

Comment: I have included "log4j-flume-ng-2.0-beta9" and "log4j-flume-ng-2.0-beta9-sources" in my library. Is it enough for my project or I need to download 58 MB "Apache Flume binary" from above link??

Comment: I understand that flume is an optional plugin. So check if you have flume enabled in your current configuration.